# Show/Hide div from code behind ASPX

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have the follow html page (With bootstrap), With button and progress as follow:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestLoading.WebForm1" %>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" OnClick="btnSend_Click" Text="Send" Width="71px" CssClass="btn btn-info" style="display: inline"/>
      <div class="progress" runat="server"  id="loadingSend">
          <div  class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="100" role="progressbar" style="display: none">
              Loading...
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I want to show/hide the **progress bar** from code behind, What I'm tried:

```
 private HttpWebRequest request;

 protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:65533/MyService.svc/");

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        HtmlControl control = FindControl("loadingSend") as HtmlControl;
        control.Style.Add("display", "block");

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), null);
    }

    void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        request.EndGetResponse(result);

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        HtmlControl control = FindControl("loadingSend") as HtmlControl;
        control.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
```

But this isn't working for me, Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make the div runat="server" and show hide in code.

```
<div id="divProgress" runat="server"  class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="100" role="progressbar" style="display: none">
  Loading...
</div>
```

In C#

```
divProgress.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks its work and show it in the button callback but in FinishWebRequest it isnt work for me

Comment: You can call this code when request ends in `btnSend_Click`

Comment: The request is async

Comment: To show set visible to true like this  `divProgress.Visible = true;`

Comment: Yeah, thats what i'm doing

Answer (score 0):

What about to show your loading indicator on client side by reacting to `OnClientClick` button handler.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" OnClick="btnSend_Click" Text="Send" OnClientClick="onBeforeSend"/>
```

So after executing and returning result, refreshing page you can disable it again.